# Get path of an item in list

Tags: vbscript, filepath

My main goal is to check if a folder exists in a zip file.
For that I'm trying to go through the various files and folders. I use the following code for that:

```
strFile = "C:\Users\temp.zip"
Set objApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objContents = objApp.NameSpace(strFile).Items()

For Each objItem in objContents
    WScript.Echo objItem.Name
    If objItem.IsFolder Then
        GetSubFolders(objItem)
    End If
Next

Sub GetSubFolders(objSubItem)
    Set objFolder = objSubItem.GetFolder

    For Each objItem2 in objFolder.Items()
        WScript.Echo objItem2.Name
        If objItem2.IsFolder Then
            GetSubFolders(objItem2)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The problem is I can't seem to figure out, how to check which level I am on.

I thought about this:

```
levelDepth = Len(strFile) - Len(Replace(strFile, "\", ""))
```

which tells me how "deep" the zip file is. If I could get the full path of `objItem` and `objItem2`, then I could use the same method. Subtract the two from each other and get how deep in the zip file the current directory or file is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb787844.aspx) property should give you the full path of an item.

Comment: please elaborate on the answer

Comment: What is there to elaborate on `objItem.Path`?

Comment: Yup... I found an answer 2-3 hours ago, but i'm giving you this because it is the same. I feel a bit stupid for missing it. Thank you for taking the time to answer it.